# Customizing Tumblr's Mobile Theme

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I was hoping to make my Tumblr blog more mobile friendly and I would like to use a mobile theme alongside my desktop theme.
I see that I can use the default mobile theme for mobile devices, but is there a way for me to customize the mobile theme, but still keep my regular theme for desktops?

Comment: No. The Default mobile theme however uses the **Global Appearance** options: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#global_appearance which you can add to your theme.

Comment: @mikedidthis is correct, but in addition you can switch off the default mobile theme completely, it's in the advanced options in Edit Theme (see here: http://41.media.tumblr.com/4a0476786fb96d6fc02f104575d40976/tumblr_nfssg1uSfQ1rqxd4qo1_1280.png) but in order for this to work you would have to code your own css using media queries. But there are lots of free responsive themes available for tumblr.

Comment: Unless something has drastically changed in the theme customization, yes you can customize your mobile theme by setting up a page for `/iphone-theme` and it will work on mobile browser -- or at least, it used to.

Comment: And no, it doesn't JUST work on iPhone. I have Android devices that it works on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just answering for people who find this while searching. I do not want them to be mislead by the comments on the question. Not happy about it.

Until now, it is possible to have separate theme for mobile devices. You have to put the codes for that in a new `Custom` page with url "[/iphone-theme](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#iphone-themes)" as @Ally also mentioned.

And yes it works for all mobile devices (not just iPhones), to be more specific for phones, even for a lot of big tablets Tumblr switches the layout to your `base theme` (here I am talking based on my tests a while ago; less than few months. You should test yourself, always.), which I think is good.

The `mobile theme` has most features like the `base theme`, it also responds to the `meta` tags (like meta-if, meta-colors, etc. That also means you can use "[Global Appearance](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#global_appearance)" options) in the `base theme`. So for example you change the option titled "Color" in your "theme customization page", which should look something like;

`<meta name="color:Color" content="#FFA500"/>` in your `base theme`'s HTML.

Then you will also affect the color in the mobile theme if the colors there are also set to something like; `body { color: {color:Color}}` or `body { background-color: {color:Color}}`. Even if the same meta tag is not present in the mobile theme.

Please note that you can not create options in the "theme customization page" with `meta tags` only in the `mobile theme`'s HTML.

I use it. Why I use it;

I have high resolution images (for "Photo" posts) on the desktop version, and JavaScript image slider for them, and some time, some browsers in mobiles devices crash for that reason (at least for my audience). Using `{PhotoURL-500}` instead of `{PhotoURL-HighRes}` solves the issue, and saves bandwidth. There is no way you can do that with `CSS @media`.

To everyone (except @Ally); do some research before replying, it's not even a new thing.

Also do not believe everything you see on the internet (at least without trusted sources).

**Update:**

The `mobile theme` overrides the "default mobile theme" so you will not have to disable the option "Use default mobile theme" in "Advanced options" to see the `mobile theme` on mobile devices. If you disable the option, you will see your `base theme`.