# Adjust the tumblr mobile theme

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821082/customizing-tumblrs-mobile-theme) and know how to override tumblr's default mobile theme with a custom theme. But I like it in general, and would just like to do a small adjustment (adding google analytics code to be precise). If I could just get the code of tumblr's default theme, I could paste it to `/iphone-theme` and make the little adjustment I want to make.

Do you know where I can find the code of tumblrs default mobile theme? I just found a very old one, but I'd like to start off with their current mobile theme.

Comment: Do you know how to debug in mobile. If you're on mac/iphone it's relatively easy as you can just hook up the phone via USB to Safari then you can inspect the properties in the console. It works similarly for android. 
1. https://medium.com/@mattcroak718/debugging-your-iphone-mobile-web-app-using-safari-development-tools-71240657c487
2. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Yes I could have a look at the source code, but its still a big step from there to reverse-engineering the underlying theme template (as seen in the [old mobile theme](https://github.com/orangkucing/Default-iPhone-theme-for-Tumblr/blob/master/iphone-theme.txt#L794), there is different code for different post types). That's why I'd like to directly have the template file.

Comment: Here is the main css file: https://static.tumblr.com/mftixld/AmMpjzwer/main-min.css  but I also found: https://assets.tumblr.com/client/prod/standalone/blog-network-npf/index.build.css?_v=3fc451676906e0ce74d518ae00bb3233 and https://assets.tumblr.com/assets/styles/mobile_handset/mh_photoset.css?_v=030213310d0e3eccef6f5f04104fffda

Comment: Well, having the css probably not bad, but i rather care for the html template

Comment: I think this is it: https://www.tumblr.com/theme/37310 Hopefully you will be able to do the rest yourself.